# MATLAB: displaying markup (HTML or other format)

Tags: html, matlab

I'd like to display a table from a script in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). I can easily generate the `<td>` and other HTML elements, but as far as I know, I can only write them to a file.

Is there a way to display HTML (or some other markup) from MATLAB? Or am I stuck writing to a file and opening a browser?

Comment: Are you wanting to display HTML directly in the command window?

Comment: in command window, you will have to use ASCII-style tables!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Java Swing component inside a MATLAB figure, precisely `JEditorPane` using MATLAB's `javacomponent()` function. JEditorPane supports a good subset of HTML.

[image]

Here is a code sample:

```
mytext  = '<html><body><table border="1"><tr><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr></table></body></html>';

hfig    = figure();
je      = javax.swing.JEditorPane( 'text/html', mytext );
jp      = javax.swing.JScrollPane( je );

[hcomponent, hcontainer] = javacomponent( jp, [], hfig );
set( hcontainer, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0,0,1,1] );

%# Turn anti-aliasing on ( R2006a, java 5.0 )
java.lang.System.setProperty( 'awt.useSystemAAFontSettings', 'on' );
je.putClientProperty( javax.swing.JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true );
je.putClientProperty( com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, true );

je.setFont( java.awt.Font( 'Arial', java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 13 ) );
```

**EDIT:** see the discussion of this solution [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-integrated-html-panel/),

Answer (score 6):

You can display the HTML text in a PopupPanel as explained here: [http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/customizing-help-popup-contents/](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-help-popup-contents/)

[image]

Or in an integrated browser control that points to your HTML file or HTML text as explained here: [http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/gui-integrated-browser-control/](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-integrated-browser-control/)

[image]

Comment: Yair, nice to see you at StackOverflow

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation when you link to your site.

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to display the table in a graphics window using the [UITABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html) control.

**EDIT:** Even though this is only an *alternative* (not a *solution*) to the problem in the question, I thought I'd include a sample for anyone who may be interested in this option:

```
hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 300 220]);
hTable = uitable(hFigure,'Data',rand(10,3),...
                 'ColumnName',{'X' 'Y' 'Z'},...
                 'Position',[20 20 260 180]);
```

[image]

Comment: +1 -- interesting... not what i'm looking for, but i'll file it away for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I didn't quite want to do, namely to write HTML to a file. It requires me to open it in a browser and refresh every time I run my script, but that's not too bad for what I needed in the short term.

Comment: If you don't want to write to a file you can use the text:// protocol. web('text://<html><body>My html text...</body></html')